# Need a solution GUI editor for Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am working on vaadin 7, the problem is with creating design,
It is really horrible creating layouts and writing css for better look , 
everything is manual for designing components.

There is a composite Editor for vaadin designing, but it doesn't really help.
Composite editor doesn't have coloring, resizing , borders, creating image component etc

Can anyone help me for an alternate GUI editor for designing vaadin components.

Thanks, Nandakishore

Answer (score 0):

Although it's horrible too and might not be what you are looking for, you can use the GWT designer in Eclipse.